# Combine two textbox value for mail in PHP

Tags: php, opencart

Hi I am currently editing my opencart website.
I added a new text box wherein they need to input a  contact number.

```
<b>Contact Number:</b><br />    
<input type="text" name="number" />

<b><?php echo $entry_enquiry; ?></b><br />
<textarea name="enquiry" cols="40" rows="10" style="width: 99%;"><?php echo $enquiry; ?></textarea>
```

This is the code in order to get the text boxes:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['number'])) {
    $this->data['number'] = $this->request->post['number'];
} else {
    $this->data['number'] = '';
}

if (isset($this->request->post['enquiry'])) {
    $this->data['enquiry'] = $this->request->post['enquiry'];
} else {
    $this->data['enquiry'] = '';
}
```

I am currently in problem because I need to combine number and enquiry. The two combined text boxes will be the setText of my mail.

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
    $mail = new Mail();
    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
    $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
    $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
    $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
    $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');             
    $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
    $mail->setSender($this->request->post['name']);
    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
    $mail->send();
```

Any help I can get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
    $enquiry_and_contact = $this->request->post['enquiry'] . "\n\n"; 
    $enquiry_and_contact .= "Contact: " . $this->request->post['number']; 

    $mail = new Mail();
    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
    $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
    $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
    $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
    $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
    $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');             
    $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
    $mail->setSender($this->request->post['name']);
    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($enquiry_and_contact, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
    $mail->send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of concatenate operator (**`.`**)

Change this

```
$mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
```

to

```
$mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry'].$this->request->post['number'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
```

**EDIT:**

```
$mail->setText(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['enquiry']." ".$this->request->post['number'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));
```

Comment: thanks it worked but now the problem is the two texts are combined leaving no spaces. Haha.
How can I now add spaces in between?